# Refresh Roles in IdentityServer-Clients

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm having an identityServer with some clients and it works great. My problem is, when one of the admins changes the roles of a user, the clients need to sign up and sign in to get the new claims and roles.

My question is, is there is a away to let the roles get updated automatically after changing the roles, without getting signed out and in?

for any help i would be very thankful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set this flag to true in the client definition to reload the claims inside the access token when you refresh them

**UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh**
Gets or sets a value indicating whether the access token (and its claims) should be updated on a refresh token request.

see https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/reference/models/client/

For refresh tokens, I add some pictures from my training class that might give a better idea about refresh tokens (you ask for them using the offline_Access scope)

When you ask for that scope and give consent, then you will get an additional "refresh token"
[image]

And using the refresh token you can then ask for new access tokens.

The picture (Taken from my training class) shows how the sliding refresh token works:

[image]

You do ask for a new token (using the refresh token) when the access token is about to expire. The lifetime of the access token is shorter than the refresh token.

You either do that manually or you use some library like [IdentityModel.AspNetCore](https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aspnetcore/overview.html) to do it for you.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I already have this flag in my clients and the claims get updated when the user sign in again. I think the problem is, i can't get the refresh token correctly. I just can't understand the difference between the refreshtoken and access_token. if you got something guid me with this i will be thankful :)

Comment: added abit more about refresh tokens.  refresh tokens are never sent to APIs, only used with your token provider.

Comment: thank you very much for your clarification. that helps alot. My only left question before start to impelemtn and test it, how can i trigger it, to ask for new "Access token" to let the claims get updated.

Comment: Does this make the question an acceptable answer? You usually login as a user to get the access + refresh token. You do need to set AllowOfflineAccess = true in the Client definition and ask for the offline_access scope.  or you use the refresh token to get a new token. see https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/tokens/refresh/

Comment: thank you for your reply. I'm trying the past time to understand, when should i request a new refresh_token, if they already have an expiration time. I think i'm missing something here. With SlidingRefreshTokenLifetime it sets when will it expires, right? then what? should it requests automatically a new refresh_token, or should i make a middleWare, where i have there to check manually, if the Refresh_token expired, then request new one? 
I'll be very thankfull if you have sample code for this part :)

Comment: Does this make the answer an acceptable answer?